# Does urllib encrypt authentication data?

Tags: python, security, urllib

If I do the following with Python's urllib, how secure is it?

```
username = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
password = getpass.getpass("And password: ")
auth = urllib.urlencode({"username": username,"password": password})
validated = urllib.urlopen('https://loginhere.com', auth)
```

Can people watching the HTTP request traffic between the user's machine and the local network get the password? Or does urllib encrypt the login data?

I have been looking at the [urllib documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) and have seen the warning about not checking https certificates, but can't see anything about encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urllib encryptes nothing, it just uses the SSL lib passed from the socket class.
urllib per sae just sends the data as you define it.

Verify SSL via:

```
import urllib2

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen('https://example.com') 
    print 'response headers: "%s"' % response.info()
except IOError, e:
    if hasattr(e, 'code'): # HTTPError
        print 'http error code: ', e.code
    elif hasattr(e, 'reason'): # URLError
        print "can't connect, reason: ", e.reason
    else:
        raise
```

Comment: So anyone watching the HTTP requests can see the password?

Comment: when passing https:// urllib will use a SSL socket tho so.. in **loose** terms urllib "encrypts" the traffic. You should be safe.

Comment: Yw, however **note** that using urllib and not verifying certificates etc etc could expose you to vulnerabilities! Just a heads up why you should dig deeper in the question! :) gl!
(There's a difference between using SSL (encrypting) and verifying that the encrypted traffic is actually secure! That's why they warn you about checking certificate data..)

Comment: Here's good information about verifying the certificate data:
http://thejosephturner.com/blog/2011/03/19/https-certificate-verification-in-python-with-urllib2/
Also don't forget to mark your question as answered **IF** you think it's solved :)